# How can I remove the marker from the map based on the list of locations?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

In this page, I have a table at the top which consists of community names and below this table I have a google map that shows the marker position of those community names placed. Now what I am trying to do is when I click the delete button (i.e. via PHP function `delete_btn()`) in the table row, I need to remove the specific marker that corresponds to the table row with the delete button position in the map. How can I achieve this?

I have posted my code structure below:

```
<div>
    <table id="sum_table">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <th>S.N.</th>
            <th>Community</th>
            <th width="18%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <? 
        $sn = 1;
        while($result= mysql_fetch_row($res))
        {
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $result[0];?>">
                <td align="center"><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $result[1] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo delete_btn("delete.php?id=", $result[0]); ?>
                </td>                       
            </tr>
            <?
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div

<?php
$query="SELECT com_name,com_lat,com_lon FROM community where mun_id=10";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var beaches = [
    <?php
    $i=0;
    if ($num>0){
        while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))   {
            ++$i;
            $i != $num ? $k=',' : $k='';
            ?>
            ['<?php echo $r['com_name'];?>',<?php echo $r['com_lat'];?>, <?php echo $r['com_lon'];?>]<?php echo $k?>
            <?php   }  }  ?>
            ];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng( beaches[0][1], beaches[0][2]),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker, i;
            var com_Image = {
                url: 'assets/img/icon/pin-single-1.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(61, 72),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 16)
            };
            var shape = {
                coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
                type: 'poly'
            };

            for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
                    icon: com_Image,
                    map: map
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.setMap()` function on a marker to remove it from the map:

> To remove a marker from the map, call the `setMap()` method passing `null` as the argument.<sup>[1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove)</sup>
>
> ```
> marker.setMap(null);
> ```
>
> Note that the above method does not delete the marker. It simply removes the marker from the map. If instead you wish to delete the marker, you should remove it from the map, and then set the marker itself to `null`.

In order to have action links in the table to delete items, we need to have the id parameter of the delete links correspond to items in the list of markers in the JavaScript code.

```
<div>
<table id="sum_table">
    <tr class="titlerow">
        <th>S.N.</th>
        <th>Community</th>
        <th width="18%">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $query="SELECT com_id, com_name,com_lat,com_lon FROM community where mun_id=10";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $sn = 1;
    $beaches = array();
    while($result= mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        //assuming 1 => com_name, 2 => com_lat, 3 => com_lon
        //assuming so, you should be able to do this instead: 
        //$beaches[] = array($result['com_name'], $result['com_lat'], $result['com_lon']);

        $beaches[] = array($result[1], $result[2], $result[3]);
        ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $result[0];?>">
            <td align="center"><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><? echo $result[1] ?></td>
            <td>
                <button class="deleteMarker" data-id="delete_<?php echo ($sn - 1)); ?>">Remove</button>
            </td>                       
        </tr>
        <?
    }

    ?>
</table>
```

Then use that `$beaches` array to create the list of markers in Javascript, and in the click handler, check for the class name (e.g. *deleteMarker*) using [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). If the element clicked has that class, then use [the data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to get the index to delete from the *data-id* attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var beaches = <?php echo json_encode($beaches); ?>;

function clickHandlerDelegate(clickEvent) {
  if (clickEvent.target.className.indexOf('deleteMarker') > -1) {
    var index = clickEvent.target.dataset.id;
    markers[index].setMap(null);
  }
}
//rest of javascript - e.g. for creating map
</script>
```

See it demonstrated in the example below (specifically in function *clickHandlerDelegate()*, which is hooked to the click events using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)).

```js
var beaches = [
  ["Haringhata", 21.984606, 89.974250],
  ["West Bengal, India",
    21.681855, 88.584980
  ]
];
var markers = [];
var map; //set scope here so various functions can use them

function clickHandlerDelegate(clickEvent) {
  if (clickEvent.target.className.indexOf('deleteMarker') > -1) {
    var index = clickEvent.target.dataset.id;
    markers[index].setMap(null);
  }
}

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[0][1], beaches[0][2]),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker);
  }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
//set up delegate
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerDelegate);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<table id="sum_table">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <th>S.N.</th>
            <th>Community</th>
            <th width="18%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
         <td>Haringhata</td>
         <td><button class="deleteMarker" data-id="0">Remove</button></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2</td>
         <td>West Bengal, India</td>
         <td><button class="deleteMarker" data-id="1">Remove</button></td></tr>
         </table>
<div id="map"></div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove

Comment: I am trying to remove one marker at the time based on the id of the table

Comment: Are the two result sets (first not included in your sample, and the second `$query="SELECT com_name,com_lat,com_lon FROM community where mun_id=10";` ) basically the same? I see the table has a column labeled "_Community_" which presumably corresponds to *com_name* so it appears they are but I can't be sure...

Comment: @S B I have updated the explanation and sample to include the table with buttons to remove each marker affiliated with the table row.

Comment: when i  add var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'}); the delete is not working

Comment: If you have another question, you can [ask another quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755055/how-can-i-update-the-marker-cluster-from-the-map-based-on-the-list-of-locations

Answer (score 0):

I create example file for do something link your want
In this code In not query data from db, I just mock the data so if you query data from db you need to format it to something like this

```
[[1, "LA", 34.0234697, -118.2532713], [2, "Chicago", 41.8718004, -87.9721186], [3, "New York", 40.7091269, -74.0112131]]
```

another thing I don't add css for tag a in table you can change it to button or add css for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Manage Map Delete in table</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <?php $results = [[1, "LA", 34.0234697, -118.2532713], [2, "Chicago", 41.8718004, -87.9721186], [3, "New York", 40.7091269, -74.0112131]];?>
      <table id="sum_table">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <th>S.N.</th>
            <th>Community</th>
            <th width="18%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <? 
        $sn = 1;
        foreach ($results as $result)
        {
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $result[0];?>">
                <td align="center"><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><? echo $result[1] ?></td>
                <td>
                  <a onClick="deleteData('<?php echo $result[0]; ?>');" >Delete</a>
                </td>                       
            </tr>
            <?
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      var markers = [];
      var listLocation = {};
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        listLocation = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
        var myLatlng = {lat:39.8004725, lng:-101.3308506}

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatlng
        });

        //add all location
        addAllLocations(listLocation);
      }

      function createLatLong(data)
      {
        var output = {}
        output["lat"] = data[2];
        output["lng"] = data[3];
        return output;
      }
      function addAllLocations(datas)
      {
        for (var i=0;i<datas.length;i++){
          //create lat long data
          var latLng = createLatLong(datas[i]);
          //add to map
          addMarker(latLng);
        }
      }

      // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }

      function deleteInTable(id)
      {
        $('#sum_table').find('#'+id).remove();
      }

      function deleteInMap(index)
      {
        markers[index].setMap(null);
      }

      function getIndex(id)
      {
        for (var i=0;i<listLocation.length;i++){
          if (listLocation[i][0] == id) {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      function deleteData(id)
      {
        //delete in table
        deleteInTable(id);
        //delete in map
        //get index
        var index = getIndex(id);
        deleteInMap(index);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[GoogleApiKey]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this help

[image]

Comment: thank you for your effort. I couldnot load any map in your code.

Comment: you need to replace [GoogleApiKey] with your key

Comment: Yes I did have google api replaced but still I cant see the map

Comment: Can you copy all code to new file name  map.php in apache and run 

http://localhost/map.php

(Don't for get replace google key) 
I do the same thing it work well, if still not work for you please tell me more about javascript error you got.